# Remove row and column names - heatmap.2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap

I am drawing a heatmap and I do not want the row names and column names to be visible on x and y axes.

So I used the following code:

```
heatmap.2(data, xlab="PROTEINS", ylab="DRUGS", labRow=FALSE, labCol = FALSE)
```

Then there is a big space between heatmap and `PROTEINS` and `DRUGS` labels on each axis.

Answer (score 11):

Try to play around with the margins parameter. Add something like:

```
#dummy data
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)

heatmap.2(x, xlab = "PROTEINS", ylab = "DRUGS",
          labRow = FALSE, labCol = FALSE,
          main = "Without xy names")

heatmap.2(x, xlab = "PROTEINS", ylab = "DRUGS",
          labRow = FALSE, labCol = FALSE,
          margins = c(2, 2),
          main = "Without xy names, margin")
```

[image]